# DataTable is not a function on Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I receive the following error in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):29)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I use the Wordpress and table press plugin. The page where I've inserted the table and I receive the problem is this one:

https://antivirusprotection.reviews/best-internet-security-software/

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem you ever load datatables.js plugin file

Comment: I use a compression plugin which concatenates the .js files, including the mentioned one.

Comment: Can also be due to several versions of jQuery being loaded. If a version loads after plugin assigned to prior version it wipes out the origional and any plugins assigned

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem:

1. I disabled/enabled the plugins, one by one: no improvement;
2. I've tried an updated version of jQuery using another plugin: no improvement;
3. I checked the functions.php file and I've found that the jQuery was overridden by the following code:

   function reassign_jQuery() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' ); // do not forget this
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' ); // do not forget this

   wp_register_script('jquery', 
   'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js', 
    array(), '1.12.4', TRUE );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
   if ( ! is_admin() )
   add_action('init', 'reassign_jQuery');

I've removed the lines and... ta-da, the problem disappeared: https://antivirusprotection.reviews/best-antivirus/

The conclusion? Some developers are not able to provide a correct code, even the theme used for this website is a paid one.

Thank you for support and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

did you add below file on your data-table code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
 });
</script>
```

removed your code and paste it when your script tag closed. That means two script tag make one is your and two is this code perfect run on WordPress.